# Cannot push to heroku

Tags: heroku, key, public-key

I have Windows 7 Home Premium with installed:

```
gem 1.8.24
ruby 1.9.3p385
node 0.8.19
git 1.8.1.msysgit.
heroku/toolbelt/2.35.0 (i386-mingw32) ruby/1.9.3
```

I can succefully login to heroku with: `heroku login`. Even when I clear keys: `heroku keys:clear` and generate new one `heroku keys:add` I have result success!

When I login to heroku webpage-> my account I have correctly added key. I'm added to project as collaborator.

```
git remote add heroku-s git@heroku.com:secret-project.git
```

Problem is, when I try to push files to heroku with:

```
git push heroku-s master
```

I get error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to re-generate the public key (`id_pub.rsa`), then add it again to heroku.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
heroku keys:clear
heroku keys:add
```

Comment: Thank you. I will add only. In folder c:\users\account\.ssh delete all files (if you don't need them). During generation of new keys, when I choosen other name then default, there was this same problem. Also after that you should config git by "git config --global user.email "your_email@youremail.com"

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that the key was being generated on my HOMEDRIVE (in my work this is F:/.ssh) but Heroku was looking in C:/Users/MYNAME/.ssh.  Copying the id_rsa files from F:/.ssh to C:/Users/MYNAME/.ssh fixed the problem.

I then ran

```
heroku.keys:add
```

afterwhich I was able to do

```
git push heroku master
```