# permission denied error when try to clone fb app in heroku to github

Tags: facebook, git, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am trying to make a fb app. I follow the tutorial in (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#working-locally," this") link. To grabbing a copy of my app’s source code using Git use the following camand in windows7 cmd.

```
 git clone git@heroku.com:myappname.git -o heroku
```

But there is an error
permission denied 
fatal :could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the curect access rights and repository exists.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, are you sure a [ssh key was set up correctly when you installed toolbelt](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#3-log-in-from-the-command-line)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14999918/cannot-push-to-heroku) has more suggestions for solving that particular problem.